# How to delete the files older than 6 months old in a directory using nodejs/expressjs?

Tags: node.js, settimeout, delete-file, unlink

Here I am not talking about the `temp` files directory.
Its about my project.

This is the following `structure` I am trying to follow to `delete the files` from a directory for every user who logins in my website:

1. The user gets an `automatic email alert` (I am using `nodemailer`) before `one week of 6 months finish` as a notification that the files are going to be deleted after `a week`, so he can take a backup if he wishes.
2. The second `automatic email alert` (I am using `nodemailer`) just before `one day of 6 months finish` that tomorrow the files will get removed.
3. Finally the day, (after `6 months` total) the files will get deleted automatically and successfully.

The code I was trying was to use `setTimeout` and with `unlink` but since the `max time` for the `setTimeout` we can put is `approx 24 days` and not more than that.

So what could be the possible ways to do that?

Comment: why on earth would you rely on code staying up and running? Do a periodic `fstat` on all files (or use a database for file metadata) and periolook at do what you need to do based on what the file age is that you discover that way. (also, why are you using code-formatting for text that isn't programming code?)

Comment: what is periodic fstat? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Just pick some time of day when your server is usually not busy (I pick 4am on my server) and run a function that looks for files that need to be cleaned up.  You can use `setTimeout()` to schedule each 4am function call.  And, you shouldn't need a separate timer for each user, just use one to do all the cleanup.  If you really want, you can even use a child process for the cleanup work so it doesn't even interfere with your main server.  Whenever your server starts up, it should schedule the next 4am timer.   Whenever it completes one, it should schedule the timer for the 4am on the next day.

Comment: or better yet, use `cron` to manage the scheduling for you, because that's why it exists. Set it to run a dedicated script once a day whose only purpose is to check file dates, and trigger emails as needed. This is not something your server should be doing alongside "being your content server".

Comment: But I want to delete the files only after 6 months so i cant run the timer everyday. @jfriend00 What is the solution for this?

Comment: You run the timer or cron job every day and scan for files that are older than 6 months.  Depending upon your implementation, you can either use the create or modification date in the file system to see the age of the files or you can separately store that date/filename in a database and query it there for dates older than 6 months and then go delete the files that match the query.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am adding my code in solution. Review it if its good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
                                          var y,m,d,h,mi,da = new Date();
                                          y = da.getFullYear();
                                          da.setMonth(da.getMonth() + 5);
                                          m = da.getMonth();
                                          d = da.getDate();
                                          h = da.getHours();
                                          mi = da.getMinutes();
                                          console.log("month = " + m);
                                         var date = new Date(y, m, d, h, mi, 0);
                                          console.log(date);
                                         var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
                                      fs.unlink(___path, function(err,success){
                                             if(err)
                                             {
                                                console.log(err);
                                                return res.end('{"msg" : "Unable to unlink the Bigpaths4Clients files : Rejected", "status" : 700}');
                                             }
                                             else {
                                               User.updateMany({"Addtasks.commonID":req.query.commonIDs},
                                               {$set: {"Addtasks.$.background" :'linear-gradient(45deg, #D70652, #FF025E)',
                                                        "Addtasks.$.status" :'Deleted'}},
                                               function (error, success) {
                                                     if (error) {
                                                       console.log("error = "+ error );
                                                     }
                                                     else {
                                                       console.log('file deleted successfully and status set as Deleted');
                                                     }
                                                   })
                                               }
                                             })
                                         }); //scheduler closed
```

Comment: Is this a proposed solution?  If so, please add some explanatory text to it as to what you did and why.  If this is just more info for the question, then it does NOT belong in an answer.  You should use the "edit" link under your question and add it to your question.  Also, please take a minute to fix the formatting of your code to make it readable here.